# Problem with react js docker image creation on silicon M1 for x86 architecture

Tags: reactjs, docker, x86, arm, apple-m1

I've been trying to make a new ReactJS image for Ubuntu VM on my local machine which supports ARM architecture.

As it turned out, there is a simple way to create it by ticking an option inside Docker Desktop settings and attaching parameter **--platform linux/amd64** while building.

Nevertheless, it doesn't work for me in ReactJS case.

Docker doesn't warn me or stop as I'm building rest of my application, it only occurs when I'm proceeding with React app.

[image: The error I received]

Did anyone have similar problem or does know what the solution is?